# Change Kubuntu desktop icon font to bold

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, plasma, desktop-icons

I have [kubuntu](/questions/tagged/kubuntu)[18.04](/questions/tagged/18.04) and I need to know how to change the desktop icons fonts to bold:

[image]

I have tried to find any css files like those in Xfce or Gnome to modify the desktop icons font style but I could not able to find any thing in `~/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme` or `~/.local/share/plasma/look-and-feel` for the current active desktop theme.

Comment: All I can find for now is *System Settings > Fonts > General*. But choosing a bold font there will **not** be limited to the desktop icons.

Comment: There's [a suggestion](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/75433-Is-it-possible-to-make-only-desktop-icon-text-font-bold?p=427381&viewfull=1#post427381) to look at *~/.config/kdeglobals* but understanding that file is beyond me. You could consider asking at [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/) or at the [KDE Forum](https://forum.kde.org/index.php).

Comment: Linked to your question @ reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/bo213q/can_the_desktop_icon_text_be_made_bold/

Comment: @DKBose Please checkout the answer based on your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [**DK Bose**](https://askubuntu.com/users/248158/dk-bose), the file he regarded in the comments `~/.config/kdeglobals` leads me to answer the question with some limitations.

[image]

**The solution**

Open the file `~/.config/kdeglobals` using kate and search for the following block of code:

```
[General]
BrowserApplication[$e]=firefox.desktop
ColorScheme=Card
Name=Card
XftAntialias=true
dbfile=/home/saidbakr/.mozilla/firefox/3tzvfegj.default/places.sqlite
fixed=Hack,9,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0,Regular
font=Noto Sans,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0,Regular
menuFont=Noto Sans,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0,Regular
shadeSortColumn=true
smallestReadableFont=Noto Sans,8,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0,Regular
toolBarFont=Noto Sans,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0,Regular
widgetStyle=Breeze
```

Replace the `Regular` in the line `font=Noto Sans,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0,Regular` by `Bold`.

By this way the desktop icons font will be in bold.

**The Limitation**

Not only desktop icons fonts will be affected, almost all folders views in Dolphin will have bold icons font.